# The List's Fields in Microsoft SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm developing a system to allow admin can add multiple fields (attributes) of an Object, the fields are not fixed. Admin can define the value type of each fields.
For example: A laptop can have the attributes:

- Manufacture: HP, Toshiba, Acer, Dell...
- CPU: Core 2 Duo x2.2
- RAM: 4GB
- VGA: 256MB
  ...
  So I want to design a database schema to solve this problem

I see that Microsoft SharePoint use one column to store XML content that define the fields of a List. All the data will be saved in user_data tables.

- Can someone tell me what are the advantages / disavantages of this method in SharePoint?
- How about the searching the content in XML Schema?
- How to apply the multilanguage for content?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest first get idea about what sharepoint list is the article below will explain the same 
[List Basics](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/working-with-sharepoint-lists-part-1-HA001119988.aspx) . in case if you have to dynamically create columns i would recommend to use SharePoint list. for the same

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a general database architecture question: should I use table schema, or stuff everything into XML in a field? And the answer is it depends on what you are storing. If the data is heirarchical, or the schema is dynamic, then it may make sense to have an XML object embedded in a field. But you may lose the performance benefit of the relational database system (depending on how it handles XML objects).

In SharePoint we don't worry too much about the underlying data structure as we try to avoid interacting with the database directly (which is unsupported) - it tends to change from release to release as the product team make improvements.

In dealing with SharePoint lists, using fields is preferred, and the SharePoint search technologies are designed to work with properties (i.e. field values). But if you have dynamic fields then XML is one of many ways you could do this.

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySQL, is that good for dealing with XML in MySQL or it should be in PHP? How about the multiple languages if using XML stored in one field and then querying to get the content?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. You need a PHP doctor or a MySQL doctor!